# Type foundries which allow free test version downloads

Tags: resource-recommendations, typefaces, typesetting

We've all seen the usual routine where normally a type foundry or shop will preview live text and allow a ridiculous PNG or GIF download. However, a few smaller foundries do offer actual font files as free-trial-limited-character-map version downloads, like [Grilli Type](https://grillitype.com) and [Pangram Pangram](https://pangrampangram.com). Anyone can add to this list?

ps. not looking for free typefaces

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you can find some on MyFonts.com using the [advanced search](http://www.myfonts.com/search/lowest_price%3A%5B%2A+TO+0%5D/fonts/) to filter out demo versions. Currently finds a little over 1000 fonts.

The search returns families of fonts, but within those families you will find weights that are free or demo weights. The process is similar to buying a real font: you have to add it to cart and check out, but the fee remains 0$.

[image: myfonts search results]